# Implement C# migration code in SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and today I got assigned an important task - to create a migration script for data in a table. From my understanding, a migration script is copying data from table A and move it to other tables B and C and so on. This seems to be frequent when database designs change constantly and the team wants to preserve data.

My task:
I have a `JobOffer` table, with the CityId field. Now the team wants to delete that field, and to preserve information they will add the CityId to the `Address` table and connect both tables using an intermidiary table called `Location` (this allows a JobOffer to have several Addresses).

[image]

I have no idea on how to perform this task. An analogy in c# of what I prentend is this:

```
foreach (var row in JobOffer)
{
    int addressId;
    if (!Address.Contains(row.CityId)){
        addressId = Address.add(row.CityId);
        Locaion.add(row.JobOfferId, addressId);
    }
    else
    {
        Locaion.add(row.JobOfferId, Address.get(row.CityId));
    }
}
```

How do I do it in SQL?

Comment: What do your tables currently look like?

Comment: They look like the Image

Comment: Sorry, I meant before the location table was created.

Comment: Are the Location and Address tables completely empty?

Comment: Location table is empty, Address table is not :S It has old data that must be kept.

Comment: I changed the question and added an analogy of what I pretend in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three tables - one for the candidates, one for the addresses (locations) and one that links the two. The third table is necessary because what you described is a many to many relationship. A single candidate may have multiple locations and a single location may house multiple candidates.

When I created similar to yours it took two scans of the input data:
The first checked if I had all the locations. If any were missing I inserted it into the location table.

The second scan inserted data into the candidate and canditatelocs table. At this point I knew for sure that I had an address for every candidate in the locations table.

Here is a description of the tables:

create table candidate (candidateid int identity primary key, idate datetime default getdate(), name varchar(200))

create table candidatelocs (candidateid int, locid int)

create table locations ( locid int identity primary key, city varchar(500), state varchar(500))